# getting the error " The <mail> type doesn't support the nested "attachments" element." with the below code

Tags: email, ant, email-attachments

```
<project name="send email" default="send_email" basedir=".">
<target name="send_email">
<mail mailhost="inetmail.domain.com" subject="testing">
<from="testing@testing.com">
<tolist="testing@testing.com">
<message="Mail testing">
<attachments>
<fileset dir="E:\ContinuousIntegration\log">
<include name="Junit_status.txt"/>
</fileset>
</attachments>
</mail>
</target>
</project>
```

unable ro send an ant email with attachment: Error: The  type doesn't support the nested "attachments" element."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for the `mail` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html) says,

> Attachments may be sent using nested `<attachments>` elements … prior to Apache Ant 1.7 only `<fileset>` has been supported as a nested element, you can still use this directly without an `<attachments>` container.

Sounds like you’re using Ant 1.6 or earlier.

Remote the `<attachments>` and `</attachments>` lines and it should work.

Comment: Hi Andrew,Thanks for your time. I amusing apache-ant-1.6.5.I am not getting the file as attachmet after removing <attchment>and </attachment>. I am just getting some code displayed on the body message

Comment: Sounds like your “The `<mail>` type doesn't support the nested ‘attachments’ element” error is fixed then. New problem, new question.

Answer (score 0):

1.Added "javax.mail.jar" to /lib folder
2.My ant is 1.6.5. Hence removed  and  and used  directly.

These 2 steps resovled the issues